# If $f$ is a bounded function on an interval E, and E has measure $0$ , Is $f$ measurable? What is the value of it's $\int_E f$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $f$ is a bounded function on an interval E, and E has measure $0$, Is $f$ measurable? What is the value of $\int_E f$?

I have the question above in Royden Analysis 4e.

Intuition suggests that f is measurable because E is , and that $\int_E f = 0$  because the lebesgue integral ignores intervals of measure 0.

If anybody could show me a more rigorous proof, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Please state the question in the body of the post in proper English and punctuation. As written, it is difficult to parse accurately.

Comment: Cleaned up the question to be easier to understand.

Comment: Do you know the definition of measurable function?

Comment: If $E$ is an interval and $\lambda(E) = 0$, then $E$ is a single point.

Comment: An interval with measure zero contains at most $1$ point. I think your question is phrased incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original exercise from Royden is as follows:

> Let $E$ have measure zero. Show that if $f$ is a bounded function on $E$, then $f$ is measurable and $\int_E f = 0.$

Let $F$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$. Then $f^{-1}(F)$ is a subset of $E$, and since subsets of measure zero sets have measure zero, $f^{-1}(F)$ has measure zero. In particular $f^{-1}(F)$ is measurable, so $f$ is measurable. Now modify the proof of Theorem 4 from section 4.2 (bounded measurable functions over a set of finite measure are integrable) to conclude that $\int_E f = 0$.

Comment: Why can you take *any* measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$? What if $F\not\subseteq\text{range}f$?

Comment: @TheCount look back at the definition of preimage of a set. You can take the preimage of any set in the codomain of $f$; it doesn't have to be in the range. Although, if it is strictly disjoint from the range, the preimage is the empty set.

Comment: @TheCount $f^{-1}(F) = \{x \in E \mid f(x) \in F\}$

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! I do recall now. I always forget that the set isn't concerned with elements outside the range of $f$.

Comment: Hi, doesn't this argument hold for any function f defined on E, not just a bounded function? From the first part of the argument you have made, we get that f is measurable, and also since integrals of any measurable function over a 0 measure set is 0, we also get integral is 0. Thanks.

Comment: Any function defined on a set of measure zero is bounded, since measure theory only cares about *essential boundedness*. On that note, any two functions defined on a set of measure zero are the same functions, since their difference is zero almost everywhere. I'm not sure what the point of this exercise was (though I also don't get the point of much of Royden's exposition, cf. Rudin/Bass)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to remove the restriction that $E$ is an interval, because otherwise it will be trivial.

Since $f$ is bounded on $E$, there exists $y \geq 0$ such that $|f\restriction_E(x)| < y$, so $|f\chi_E| < y \chi_E$, where $\chi_E$ is the characteristic function of $E$. Then
$$ \left| \int_E f\,d\lambda \right| \leq \int \left|f\chi_E \right|\,d\lambda
\leq \int y \chi _E\,d\lambda = y\lambda(E) = 0
$$
Since $\lambda$ is a complete measure, the above integrands are all integrable.

The measurability of $f$ cannot be determined if you only know that it is bounded on $E$.

Comment: What are the half arrows?

Comment: @user3677952 They are called "harpoons", meaning restriction to.

Comment: You cannot write $\int_E f d\lambda$ unless you know it exists. In this case, we must prove first that $f$ is indeed measurable, and then that it is integrable.